# Is my question privilege revoked just because I am less active?

Tags: support, post-ban

First of all I am banned from asking questions,  my first thought was maybe I asked some stupid questions in past but there are no questions from my account.

Then I thought maybe I have too many bad answers, but I have a single -2 voted answer, 2 selected answers with 0 votes, 2 single upvoted answers and maybe 1 or 2 0 votes unaccepted answers.

I thought about improving over whatever reason I was banned for, but the reasons for which people normally get question banned is just not there. Why then was I question banned and how can I get it uplifted?

Comment: You may have deleted questions you've forgotten about

Comment: There are no deleted questions as well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I am not asking what to do, my primary question is "why" am I banned?  Secondarily I want to know if something special needs to be done in my case as I do not have any poor questions, editing which is supposed to be the first task.

Comment: @rijulgupta You *do* have deleted questions.  As to what you're asking for, all of that is covered in the duplicate question, at least with as much detail as anyone will ever be able to give you.

Comment: To get the ban lifted, answer some questions and get some upvotes. However, please do this with some care - don't just post the shortest answer that will get you an upvote. We like answers that are helpful for future users as well as OPs here - and those sorts of answers will get your more upvotes anyway.

Comment: Eventually, instead of being banned completely, you'll just be throttled so that you can still ask questions, but just not a lot until your questions start improving. See [No one likes quitting cold turkey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230857/163250).

Answer (score 7):

In the [question Josh linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) it was written in quite large letters:

> [**READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584)

From your comments, I'm assuming you **haven't read** everything that post tried to tell you, so here goes:

> Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts,
>   including auto-deleted old low-score questions, all of which are only
>   visible to moderators.

**You** can only view **deleted recent** posts (posts that were posted within the last 90 days and then deleted), not old ones as you can see from the screenshot below.

[image]

Therefore, I believe you can assume that you have written some pretty bad posts earlier that you're now paying the price for.

[Andrew Barber](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) just confirmed that you have (at least) two older deleted posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064832/upload-seed-in-torrents) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615875/comparing-between-restart-and-shutdown-of-a-computer) ([10k+ users only](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)).

Comment: There are two older deleted questions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064832/upload-seed-in-torrents) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615875/comparing-between-restart-and-shutdown-of-a-computer)

Comment: Oh definitely, yes :) In fact, you're welcome to include those links in your answer.